# Microcontroller Feature - Compatibility

Tags: microcontroller

I am going through a datasheet of AT89C51. The very first feature in the datasheet mentions it be --> Compatible with MCS-51™ Products. what does this mean exactly?

Comment: It means it will run all programs designed for *the* 8051, not limited to this particular MCU.

Answer (score 1):

Intel MCS-51, usually called 8051. Being compatible means the device uses the same instruction set as the 8051-devices so any code written for those should work on this AT89C51.